# Volume of Revolution about y=1

Tags: calculus, volume

I have two functions and I am attempting to find the area enclosed by each when rotated around $y=1$. These said functions $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Upon graphing this it seemed simple however I am not sure what to integrate. So far I have:

Intercept: $(1,1)$, Its bounds are between $0$ and $1$.

To find the right angled triangled area without considering $y=\sqrt{x}$, so I did: $$\int_{0}^1 (1-x)^2\pi \,dx =\frac{\pi}{3}$$ then the area enclosed by the square root, so I did: $$\int_{0}^1 (\sqrt{x}-x)^2\pi \,dx =\frac{\pi}{30}$$

Then I did $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{3\pi}{10}$ to get my answer of $\frac{\pi}{30}$ however I know the answer should be $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Can anyone shed some light? Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^1 (\pi (1-x)^2-\pi(1-\sqrt{x})^2 )dx$

This is what I did:

Do bigger circle area minus smaller circle area like

$\pi \cdot R^2-\pi \cdot r^2$